# afterSend? onClose? less intrusive alternative to onSend?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are developing an outlook add-in. One feature requested by users is the ability to send a copy of an email to our main application. For already composed emails we are able to use item.subject.getAsync, body to from etc to grab the email data and pass it along as needed.

Compose is another issue. We could grab all the info before the user has sent the email but there is an obvious issue of the email becoming out of sync if we copy it to our app and they continue to edit.

We looked into using the onSend function but this requires an admin to install and then the add-in can't be in the store. The onSend function is more powerful than what we need as well, allowing the add-in to change the email etc. We only need to get a copy of the data.

Is there a way to just get the email data afterSend on onClose of the email or taskpane?

Answer (score 0):

You may find the *appendOnSend* feature (which is still in preview) helpful. It is fired after the onSend one and allows to run actions you need. See [Implement append on send in your Outlook add-in (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/append-on-send#how-to-preview-the-append-on-send-feature) for more information.

Comment: Thanks we had noticed that but saw it was in preview. Is there a release date for this? 

We also saw https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.addincommands.event?view=word-js-preview#completed-options- but were unsure if this would work for our case. Any advice on this route?

Comment: The completed method must be called at the end of a function which was invoked, it is not an event which you can handle.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! 2 questions here. 


Are both appendOnSend and onSend always fired? The use case here is for a user to select if they want an email to also be copied to our app via api not for all sent emails to be copied. 2nd part: These command fuctions have no context or shared state with the taskpane correct? The user is always required to auth with our app for the connection to the api. Im guessing the commands would not have access to app state. Maybe local storage items?

Comment: Just to clarify, AppendOnSend API wouldn't help here. It's merely an API that allows appending some content during send, but you wouldn't be able to run any code to access email content at that point - at the moment when send happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible today. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). It looks like the feature you want has been requested by others already. Please upvote the [existing request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/40183891-aftersend-event-for-outlook). Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Until then, it may be possible to solve this by complementing the add-in with a backend service component that would subscribe to and process send events via [Outlook REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/).

Comment: Thanks! I have upvoted that and commented to specify that it would need to be UI based as well.